# Turning a .xlsx into multiple PDFs

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, openpyxl

I have a python script that takes an .xlsx file with multiple worksheetes and splits each one of them into a seperate PDF with the worksheet name as the new file name.

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def xlsx_to_pdf(filename):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    for ws in wb:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
        with PdfPages(f"{ws.title}.pdf") as pdf:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.axis('tight')
            ax.axis('off')
            the_table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,
                                  colLabels=df.columns,
                                  cellLoc='center',
                                  loc='center')
            pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')

xlsx_to_pdf("Provisionsabrechnung.xlsx")
```

The only problem I have is that the lines on the tabel it creates are really thick and the text is super small.
[imported worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnDq9.png)
[exported PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81DnZ.png)

Since I'm a complete Python noob I would really appreciate any tips.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just need to adjust the fontsize with [`Table.set_font_size`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/table_api.html#matplotlib.table.Table.set_fontsize) (*after turning off the auto-size*) :

```
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(12) # <- adjust the size here
```

And for the borders, you can make thin borders with [`table.Cell.set_linewidth`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/table_api.html#matplotlib.table.Cell.set) for each cell separatly :

```
cell.set_linewidth(0.3) # <- adjust the width here
```

*The full code :*

```
def xlsx_to_pdf(filename):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    for ws in wb:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
        with PdfPages(f"{ws.title}.pdf") as pdf:
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            ax.axis("tight")
            ax.axis("off")
            the_table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,
                                  colLabels=df.columns,
                                  cellLoc="center",
                                  loc="center")
            the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
            the_table.set_fontsize(10)
            for _, cell in the_table._cells.items():
                cell.set_linewidth(0.5)
            pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches="tight")

xlsx_to_pdf("file.xlsx")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Awesome - thank you @Timeless
Is it possible to add a line break after a certain number of characters per column? Right now parts of the text still overlap.